# Definite shape of polyominos

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

I'm currently exploring polyominoes and there's this question I'm pondering on. It said, "how can you convince yourself that a new shape is really 'different' from those already obtained?". I know that if two shapes can fit on top of one another, either by rotation or reflection, they are not unique. My question is, how can I better explain this reasoning? How can it be explained mathematically to be more convincing? (can it?)

Thank you so much for any help you can offer.

Comment: So what is a polynominoe?

Comment: Basically a polymino is formed by the joining of one or more equal squares side by side. I drew a polymino in my previous question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1434813/different-shapes-made-from-particular-number-of-squares

Comment: I can see more than one interpretation of the question, so in order to narrow it down: are you asking how to justify the claim that two polyominos are really the same polyomino if there's a way to rotate and reflect one so that it perfectly covers another? Or are you asking how to index them so that when you're counting by hand you can be sure that you don't have duplicates? Or are both of those interpretations wrong and it's something else?

Comment: @PeterTaylor, your first interpretation's correct. :) I mean, will that claim suffice if I were to say that it's a different shape from those obtained because the new shape doesn't fit on top of another shape? Or is there a much better way of explaining that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you just *define* the objects you're counting as *equivalence classes* under rotation and reflection.

The longer answer is that polyominos are an example of a combinatorial object whose identity can be defined in more than one way. (Other examples would be tilings, trees, colourings, ...). In particular, polyominos can have symmetry and can be related to each other by symmetries. With these kind of objects, it's typical that people should want to count

- The number of distinct objects ignoring all symmetries (e.g. for polyominos this is the OEIS' [A000105](http://oeis.org/A000105))
- The number of distinct objects having a given symmetry (e.g. [polyominos with no symmetry](http://oeis.org/A006749), [polyominos with every symmetry possible](https://oeis.org/A142886))
- The number of distinct objects when you identify an object with those it relates to by a symmetry (e.g. for polyominos this is [A001168](http://oeis.org/A001168))

Since polyominos are built up from squares, the symmetries of a polyomino must be a subset of the symmetries of a square. The *symmetry group* of a square has eight elements: the easy way to argue this is that any of the four corners can be mapped to the top-left, and then there are two choices for the corner which is mapped to the top-right. It turns out to have [10 subgroups](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/w/images/b/bc/D8latticeofsubgroups.png) (including itself and the trivial group), so there are 10 types of symmetry which a polyomino can have. (None, only vertical, only horizontal, only main-diagonal, only anti-diagonal, rotation by 180, rotation by 90, vertical + horizontal + rotation 180, main-diagonal + anti-diagonal + rotation 180, all four reflections + rotation by 90). Each of them has a symmetry group whose size is a factor of 8, and the number of distinct objects in the equivalence class is 8 divided by that size. E.g. the Z tetromino

```
##
 ##
```

has a symmetry group of size 2 (the "do nothing" operation, and a rotation by 180 degrees), so there are $\frac{8}{2} = 4$ objects in its equivalence class:

```
##    #   ##  #
 ##  ##  ##   ##
     #         #
```