# Given N blocks, find the number of unique shapes in a NxN block

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Constraints:
The blocks must be adjacent to each other. i.e. A pair of blocks must have a common edge or vertex.
Any shapes that are formed by flipping or rotating or mirroring should be considered to be the same shape.

By manual inspection, for example,
For N=2, there are 2 unique shapes in a 2x2 grid

```
[][]

[]
  []
```

For N=3, there are 5 unique shapes in a 3x3 grid

```
[][][]


[][]
[]


[]
  [][]


[]  []
  []


[]
  []
    []
```

I can find the total number of shapes using the combination formula, nCr

For r=2 and n=2x2=4, we get 4C2 = 6 shapes (4+2)

For r=3 and n=3x3=9, we get 9C3 = 84 shapes (6+16+16+8+2) + 36 non-adjacent

Need help in finding out mathematically or algorithm-wise,

- how to identify non-adjacent blocks
- how to identify mirror patterns
- how to identify rotating/flippable patterns

Similar questions were asked in the following links but I wasn't able to extrapolate any concrete solutions.

[link1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193689/how-many-shapes-can-one-make-with-n-square-shaped-blocks?rq=1)

[link2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1434813/different-shapes-made-from-particular-number-of-squares)

I tried researching graph theory for ways to identify identical shapes (mirror, rotate, flip).

Comment: By your stated rules, there are $5$ unique shapes for $N=2$: You omit the single block, the $L$ shape, and the full grid.  Did you mean the queivalent of "How many distinguishable length-$N$ non-self-intersecting paths are there in an $N\times N$ square grid such that for all $k$, the $k+1$-st vertex on the path is adjacent or diagonally adjacent to the $k$-th entry?

Comment: I don't understand yet, some shapes seem to be missing in the list for $3$.

Comment: For N=2, there are just 2 unique shapes. You cant form a L with 2 blocks, nor can you occupy the full grid (you need 4 blocks!).

Comment: Can you identify the missing shapes for N=3? If you plot your missing shapes on a 3x3 grid, you will observe that they are identical to the 5 unique shapes.

Comment: Observe that for the 3x3 if you shift your shape number three to the right with wrap-around it becomes a flipped copy of number four. Do you or don't you admit toroidal symmetry? Under dihedral symmetry there are two horizontal segments, one passing through the center and the other one in contact with a boundary of the grid. Apparently you consider these to be the same. Under toroidal symmetry number five disconnects when shifted to the right.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, Marko. I couldn't visualize the symmetries you are referring to. According to the constraints (every block must be attached to another by an edge or vertex), I have those 5 shapes covered correctly.

Comment: If you admit toroidal symmetry so that the horizontal bar at the top of the grid is the same as the bar passing thorugh the center then you generate all toroidal symmetries. Once you admit those you get symmetries that disconnect previously connected shapes, making for an inconsistent problem definition.

Comment: Sorry I cannot be more precise or mathematical about the problem statement than in the heading above. I could try working out N=4 to make things clearer. But that would be a tad tedious and unnecessary at this point. Can you suggest a solution based on what you have understood? I am not interested in the math behind it as much as the formula or algorithmic approach.